# How to create remote branch in SAP Web IDE Git?

Tags: sap-web-ide

I am using `WEB IDE` currently for a development. I created a local repository first and connected it to SAP HCP Git repository for my project and it works fine. Just when I use `+` button to create a new branch it just create a local branch and does not create a remote branch. How can create a same remote branch and push to that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here you will find what you need: [Create Remote Branch](https://help.sap.com/viewer/825270ffffe74d9f988a0f0066ad59f0/latest/en-US/99aa5b52bf59485c811d8291aaa5d424.html)

1. Left click on your Project
2. Select Git
3. Create Remote Branch